# The $Hol$ operator is a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a compact space, and consider $C(\Omega)$ the space of 
the continuous functions over $\Omega$, consider also, $C^\gamma(\Omega)$ the 
space of all $\gamma$-holder continuous functions, i.e, $f\in C(\Omega)$ s.t
$$
Hol(f):=\sup_{x\neq y}\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{d(x,y)^{\gamma}}<\infty
$$

My problem is the following: Let $(f_n)\subset C^\gamma(\Omega)$ be a sequence
of Holder continuous functions s.t  $f_n$ converge uniformly to a constant function $f\equiv F.$

It is clearly that $Hol (f)=0$, my question: It is truth that $Hol(f_n)\to 0$?

Comment: In the definition of the Holder seminorm, the absolute value is missing.

Answer (score 2):

For $\gamma = .$ NO. Let $\Omega =[0,1].$ For $n\in N,$ for $x\in  [1/n,1]$ let $f_n(x)=0$ and for $x\in [0,1/n)$ let $f_n(x)=1/n-x.$ Then Hol$_1(f_n)=1$ but $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $0.$

Comment: In fact, in this example $\mathrm{Hol}_{\gamma}(f_n)\to 0$ unless $\gamma=1$. Nevertheless, this idea can be developed into a working example: $f_n(x) = (n^{-\gamma} - x^\gamma)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}(x)$.

Comment: @zhoraster .Right.I originally had $\gamma=1$ and mistakenly changed it to $\gamma \in (0,1]$....I changed it back . I like your general case.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in user254665's post, the answer is negative. But under some additional assumptions this convergence takes place.

A simple sufficient condition is that $\Omega$ is compact (or just totally bounded) and $\{f_n,n\ge 1\}$ is bounded in $C^{\gamma'}(\Omega)$ with $\gamma'>\gamma$, i.e. $\sup_{n\ge 1} \mathrm{Hol}_{\gamma'}(f_n)<\infty$. Indeed, in this case the embedding $C^{\gamma'}(\Omega)\subset C^{\gamma}(\Omega)$ is compact, so $\{f_n,n\ge 1\}$ is precompact in $C^{\gamma}(\Omega)$. But since $f_n$ converges in $C(\Omega)$, it must converge in $C^\gamma(\Omega)$ as well.